# Is my eval wrong or do I not understand eq vs == in Perl

Tags: perl

I am having trouble understand eval or maybe I do not understand `eq` vs `==`.
I have this short Perl script:

```
[red@tools-dev1 ~]$ cat so.pl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($arg1, $arg2, $op ) = split /,/;
    if ( $op eq '=' ) {
        $op = 'eq';
    }
    my $cmd = "$arg1 $op $arg2";
    print "[$cmd]\n";
    my $rc = eval $cmd || 0;
    print "rc is [$rc]\n";
}

__DATA__
cat,cat,=
```

When I execute it I get:

```
[red@tools-dev1 ~]$ ./so.pl
[cat eq cat]
rc is [0]
```

One would think that you'd get ...

```
[cat eq cat]
rc is [1]
```

... since "cat" equals "cat", right?

Comment: Try printing $@ after the eval; you'll see any errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using barewords in strict mode, which is an error:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; cat eq cat'
Bareword "cat" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Bareword "cat" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Whenever you `eval` a string, you should check `$@` to see if there was an error.

Answer (score 8):

Others have pointed out the root of your problem. I am going to recommend you avoid using string `eval` for this purpose. Instead, you can use a lookup table:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %ops = (
'=' => sub { $_[0] eq $_[1] },
);

while(my $test = <DATA>) {
    next unless $test =~ /\S/;
    $test =~ s/\s+\z//;
    my ($arg1, $arg2, $op ) = split /,/, $test;
    if ($ops{$op}->($arg1, $arg2)) {
        print "'$arg1' $op '$arg2' is true\n";
    }
}
__DATA__
cat,cat,=
```

Comment: Nice and simple ... operators in a lookup table and no need for `overload`.

Answer (score 3):

You have barewords, not strings, so you'll have to compare them as variables.

```
my $cmd = qq{\$arg1 $op \$arg2};
```

Instead of `eval`, consider using functions,

```
my %f = (
  "eq" => sub { my ($x, $y) = @_; $x eq $y },
  "==" => sub { my ($x, $y) = @_; $x == $y },
  # ..
);
# ..
$f{$op} or die "unknown $op";
my $rc = $f{$op}->($arg1, $arg2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
my $cmd = "\$arg1 $op \$arg2";
```

This will assign the string

```
$arg1 eq $arg2
```

to `$cmd` instead of

```
cat eq cat
```

which is illegal under `use strict;`. Had you checked the exception `eval` caught (`$@`), you would have known this.

---

But why are you using `eval` at all?

```
my $rc;
if ($op eq '=') {
   $rc = $arg1 == $arg2;
} else {
   $rc = $arg1 eq $arg2;
}
```

or even

```
my $rc = $op eq '=' ? $arg1 == $arg2 : $arg1 eq $arg2;
```

If you actually have more than two ops, you might want to use use a dispatch table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. I don't really understand what you want from your script. But your eval expression is in fact expended into:

eval cat eq cat || 0;

which makes no sense at all.

If you are trying to compare whether $arg1 is the same as $arg2, why not do it directly?

$rc=0;
$rc=1 if ($arg1 eq $arg2);